# Git rebasing issue - should I "push --force origin"

Tags: git

I seem to have messed up my git repo, probably by committing the sin of "Do not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository."

The scenario is this:

- I track changes from a upstream repository in my master branch, I keep my own changes in a branch called devel.
- When there is a change in the upstream repository I pull this into the master branch.
- I then checkout devel and do a `rebase master` on it, to get my own changes on top of the master branch. This creates causes conflicts, giving the following error message to come up at several of the commits (I include only one of them below as an example):

> Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge... Auto-merging
>   public/scala/qscript/org/broadinstitute/sting/queue/qscripts/AlignWithBWA.scala
>   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in
>   public/scala/qscript/org/broadinstitute/sting/queue/qscripts/AlignWithBWA.scala
>   Failed to merge in the changes. Patch failed at 0038 Added checking
>   for index files.
>
> When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue". If
>   you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
>   To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase
>   --abort".

- I then use `git rebase --skip` to skip the commits causing the problems, and finally I end up with the code I want.

Now, the problem is, *every time* I want to rebase I have to go through this procedure. Is there any way for me to avoid getting the same conflicts in the future? My idea is to use `push --force origin devel`, to overwrite the history in the remote repo with out the commits that cause the conflicts. Is this the way to go? Or is there some other way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming upstream is not rewriting public history, you should be adjusting your commits to work on top of the latest code from master.  Instead, you are skipping commits that conflict.  You need to instead resolve the conflicts and then mark them resolved by using `git add`, and then `git rebase --continue` (not `--skip`).

The reason the conflicts keep occurring is because you are skipping them each time.

Doing a `git push --force` would rewrite public history for other people using the branch (you could possibly remove or reorder commits that they already have pulled down and worked on top of).  This is best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

push force should only be done in the most dire of circumstances.

If any changes have been made to the remote branch by anyone else since you started your work you will literally over-write them.

So you are best of resolving the conflicts manually.

If the code has changes on the same lines, you'll need to resolve them manually.  Using force is not a way to 'resolve' them.

You will not get the conflicts every time, if that has been your experience it is just while you're learning and a few things are probably off while you are doing that, experimenting and learning.

Another option to consider might be to just take the code, make a copy, delete -r the .git directory and make a new git repo for it (git init).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `git push --force` is a good idea here. In any case before using `git push --force` you should do thing like `git fetch` and `git diff devel origin/master` to review what things are you adding and removing with the push and keep in mind that after `--force` other developers will receive warnings and will probably need to rebase and re-push their changes.

1. I expect that with `git rebase --skip` you are skipping your devel's commits, not fetched master's ones;
2. After "rebase" should be be able to push without "--force" (unless new commits come there quickly enough to require another cycle of fetch/rebase).

Some notes:

- If you don't want to resolve the same conflicts over and over you can use "git rerere"
- Git automatically mirrors the remote content as "origin/master", you can use "git fetch" to update it. Then you can use "git rebase origin/master" in your devel without needing to switch back and forth to/from "master" branch.